# Include half-space (\u200c) in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

In regex for example in Python when I use:

```
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
```

Then using:

```
w = 'This is a test'
WORD.findall(w)
```

I get:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Now I want to treat `half-space` character, which is `\u200c` as a normal alphanumerical character so if I have:

```
w = 'This\u200cis a test'
```

Then when I run `WORD.findall(w)` I get:

```
['This\u200cis', 'a', 'test']
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to include `\u200c` in addition to `\w` (Python 3.x+):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[\u200c\w]+', 'This\u200cis a test')
['This\u200cis', 'a', 'test']
```

In Python 2.x, you need to use unicode:

```
>>> re.findall(u'[\u200c\w]+', u'This\u200cis a test')
[u'This\u200cis', u'a', u'test']
```